# trouble installing pycurl on mac 10.8.5

Tags: python, macos, libcurl, pycurl

I really have trouble installing pycurl on the mac of my girlfriend, I managed to do it on my own but I did not remember which command brought the success. Everything I tried on her mac wont't work.

I looked up every answer I could find on how to install pycurl, nothing worked for me :(. I tried macports, didn't work as well. The problem is, I am not that into using the terminal

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
sudo port install py27-yaml
sudo port install py27-curl
/opt/local/bin/python2.7
import pycurl
```

but id didn't ' work :(

trying `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" easy_install setuptools pycurl==7.19.0`

brings me this

```
Last login: Wed Oct  9 23:51:34 on ttys000
Loras-MacBook-Air:~ Lora$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" easy_install setuptools pycurl==7.19.0
Searching for setuptools
Best match: setuptools 0.6c12dev-r88846
setuptools 0.6c12dev-r88846 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Processing dependencies for setuptools
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools
Searching for pycurl==7.19.0
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/
Reading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/
Reading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/
Best match: pycurl 7.19.0
Downloading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
Processing pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
Running pycurl-7.19.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-r7sdRe/pycurl-7.19.0/egg-dist-tmp-DKaHyW
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.32.0)
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
src/pycurl.c:1168:16: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision:
      'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            ret = dup(PyInt_AsLong(fileno_result));
                  ~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/pycurl.c:1912:31: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision:
      'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        val = PyLong_AsLong(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(t, j));
                            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/pycurl.c:2904:22: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision:
      'long' to '__darwin_suseconds_t' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        tv.tv_usec = (long)(timeout*1000000.0);
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding pycurl 7.19.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pycurl-7.19.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for pycurl==7.19.0
Finished processing dependencies for pycurl==7.19.0
Loras-MacBook-Air:~ Lora$
```

i just cant get i done :(

Comment: I see no error in the output of `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" easy_install setuptools pycurl==7.19.0`, have you tried importing `pycurl` into this `/opt/local/bin/python2.7` python and/or after a simple `python` command? It seem from another SO question that you possibly have two python installations.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple LLVM compiler in Xcode 5.1 treats unrecognized command-line options as errors. This issue has been seen when building both Python native extensions and Ruby Gems, where some invalid compiler options are currently specified. from [Kasper Munck](http://kaspermunck.github.io/2014/03/fixing-clang-error/)

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future easy_install-2.7  pycurl
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no mac, but I think the output is relatively clear:

```
port: command not found
```

This probably means no macports is installed and you need to do that first. This seem to be pretty easy if you follow the instructions [here](https://www.macports.org/install.php). After that you shoul be able to use the `port` command.

Comment: i managed getting the port command done, but didn't work at the end :(

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you not to use `port`, but download and install `brew+pip` and then install `pycurl` using `pip`. These are the steps

1)[Homebrew](http://brew.sh)
or simply enter "ruby -e "curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go" in terminal"(without the outermost quote)

2)Then install pip by entering in terminal: "brew install pip in shell"

3)And then again in terminal "sudo pip install pycurl"

Comment: I would be happy to know why did I get a minus vote?!